# Sharing speakers between a Mac and PC running Windows 7 on LAN

Tags: windows, mac, audio, streaming, speakers

I would like to be able to share speakers between my roommate's MacBook and my Windows 7 PC. Mostly for streaming music.

I've tried VLC player for this, but it's kind of cumbersome because you can't seem to add songs on the fly to the playlist, or skip around.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook the speakers to an AirPort Express. iTunes for Windows or Mac can stream to it natively, and for all other apps, there's Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) for both Windows and Mac. For that matter, their [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) tool is free, and lets either your Windows box or your Mac be the audio output device, eliminating the need for an AirPort Express.

Answer (score 1):

Errrr...why not just do it using cables? For instance run the line-out of your friend's mac in to the line-in on your PC and then just adjust using the volume in Windows?

If you can spend a bit more look why not look at using speakers/amp with more than one input?